# Array em java mudando sozinha

Tags: java, array

Tentando criar um método para trocar aleatoriamente 2 linhas de uma matriz [n][2], sempre que tento criar essa nova matriz, ela altera a anterior também, não importa o que eu faça, ou seja, após eu executar essas linhas de código, o valor de individuos[0].ordemIndividuos, de alguma forma se altera e fica igual a newSon.

```
            int[][] newSon = new int[coordenadasX.length/2][2];
            newSon = individuo[0].ordemIndividuos; 
            int random1 = r1.nextInt(coordenadasX.length);
            int random2 = r1.nextInt(coordenadasX.length);

            int temp1 = newSon[random1][0];
            int temp2 = newSon[random1][1];

            newSon[random1][0] = newSon[random2][0];
            newSon[random1][1] = newSon[random2][1];

            newSon[random2][0] = temp1;
            newSon[random2][1] = temp2;
```

Comment: O que é `individuo[0]`? O que é `r1`? Se na segunda linha você está atribuindo algo a `newSon`, então o que você atribuiu na primeira linha será esquecido.

Comment: Ah, e se `newSon = individuo[0].ordemIndividuos`, então qualquer mudança em `newSon` será uma mudança em `individuo[0].ordemIndividuos`, pois `newSon` é a variável que você está usando para referenciar o `individuo[0].ordemIndividuos`. Talvez o que você quisesse era fazer com que `newSon` fosse uma cópia de `individuo[0].ordemIndividuos`, e não o próprio `individuo[0].ordemIndividuos`.

Comment: é exatamente isso, individuo[0] é um vetor da classe individuo, e r1 é um objeto da classe Random, como eu copio individuo[0] para newSon?

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés disso:

```
int[][] newSon = new int[coordenadasX.length/2][2];
newSon = individuo[0].ordemIndividuos;
```

Faça isso:

```
int[][] original = individuo[0].ordemIndividuos;
int[][] newSon = new int[original.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    newSon[i] = original[i].clone();
}
```

Baseado [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1686523/540552).